# what is background ANR? How it differs from ANR?

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

Question is simple, in system logs of my app I got background [ANR](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr.html) for `receiver` and the thread id is other than UI. Want to understand Background ANR and possible ways of occurrence of it.

Comment: This seems like a good question that may help others too. Please consider adding some other information that may lead to the root cause of the problem.

Comment: What is ANR? What is BG? What is bg? What is Anr?

Comment: Everything you need to know is written the logcat. Usually, an ANR's log specifies what is the cause, or at least where it come from

Comment: From https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr.html                   

Android shows ANR dialogs for apps that take too long to process the broadcast message only if Show all ANRs is enabled in the device’s Developer options. For this reason, background ANR dialogs are not always displayed to the user, but the app could still be experiencing performance issues.  Is it mean bg ANR can cause only delay happened in broadcasts.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a detailed explanation about "bg anr" in official manuals, but there are some clues in the source code of android framework:

```
final void appNotResponding(...) {
    ...
    synchronized (mService) {
        isSilentANR = !showBackground && !isInterestingForBackgroundTraces(app);
        ...
    }
    ...
    File tracesFile = ActivityManagerService.dumpStackTraces(
            true, firstPids,
            (isSilentANR) ? null : processCpuTracker,
            (isSilentANR) ? null : lastPids,
            nativePids);

    synchronized (mService) {
        if (isSilentANR) {
            app.kill("bg anr", true);
            return;
        }
        ...

        //Show anr dialog
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.what = ActivityManagerService.SHOW_NOT_RESPONDING_UI_MSG;
        msg.obj = new AppNotRespondingDialog.Data(app, activity, aboveSystem);
        mService.mUiHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

The silentANR in the above code means meeting the both following conditions:

- It's a **bg anr**
- **Show all ANRs** is not enabled in the device’s **Developer options**

And a silentANR will not show ANR dialog, but kill the App process directly

So the function `isInterestingForBackgroundTraces(app)` **determines whether it's a fg anr or bg anr**, refer https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.0.0_r4/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/AppErrors.java#756

```
static boolean isInterestingForBackgroundTraces(ProcessRecord app) {
    // The system_server is always considered interesting.
    if (app.pid == MY_PID) {
        return true;
    }
    // A package is considered interesting if any of the following is true :
    //
    // - It's displaying an activity.
    // - It's the SystemUI.
    // - It has an overlay or a top UI visible.
    //
    // NOTE: The check whether a given ProcessRecord belongs to the systemui
    // process is a bit of a kludge, but the same pattern seems repeated at
    // several places in the system server.
    return app.isInterestingToUserLocked() ||
        (app.info != null && "com.android.systemui".equals(app.info.packageName)) ||
        (app.hasTopUi || app.hasOverlayUi);
}
```

**To summarize**, the decision of whether it's an fg or bg anr depends on whether the App is perceptible to the user when an anr occurs. For example, a process with an activity currently visible in the foreground, or a process with an fg-service with a foreground notification. These are the cases that the user can perceive when an anr occurs. It has a great impact on the user experience, so a pop-up dialog is needed to let the user decide whether to exit or wait. If you directly kill this type of App, it will cause an inexplicable crash for the user.

Compared with fg anr, **bg anr will be killed directly in the background without dialog for the user**, unless **Show all ANRs** is enabled in the device’s **Developer options**. And it's disabled by default.

There are also some test results to prove it:

Firstly I defined a Broadcast receiver to just sleep 100s in the `onReceive()` method.

Then test it with `sendOrderedBroadcast()` and `sendBroadcast()`:

|  | sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null) | sendBroadcast(intent) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| - App displaying an activity (no matter whether **Show all ANRs** is enabled) | anr occurs, with dialog | no anr at all |
| - App not displaying any activity - **Show all ANRs** is disabled | anr occurs, app was killed without dialog | no anr at all |
| - App not displaying any activity - **Show all ANRs** is enabled | anr occurs, with dialog | no anr at all |

By the way, whether it's a `FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND` has nothing to do with whether it's a fg anr or bg anr. But it determines the time, here is the test result:

| `// with this flag` `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);` `sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);` | `// no flag` `sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);` |
| --- | --- |
| anr occurs after blocking **10s** | anr occurs after blocking **60s** |

- test device: Emulator Pixel 5 API 31

Thanks to Gityuan:

- http://gityuan.com/2019/04/06/android-anr/
- http://gityuan.com/2016/06/04/broadcast-receiver/